# Unix Bash content of a file as argument stops at first line

Tags: bash, unix

I'm having an issue in something that seems to be a rookie error, but I can't find a way to find a solution.

I have a bash script : log.sh
which is :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 >> log_out.txt
```

And with a file made of filenames (taken from the output of "find" which names is filesnames.txt and contains 53 lines of absolute paths) I try :

```
./log.sh $(cat filenames.txt)
```

the only output I have in the log_out.txt is the first line.
I need each line to be processed separately as I need to put them in arguments in a pipeline with 2 softwares.
I checked for :

- my lines being terminated with /n
- using a simple echo without writing to a file
- all the sorts of `cat filenames.txt` or (< filenames.txt) found on internet

I'm sure it's a very dumb thing, but I can't find why I can't iterate more than one line :(

Thanks

Comment: you'll need to show us (in a greatly reduced example) what does your input(s) look like and what do you need for output. What you have so far will just copy the first filename (not it's contents) to the `log_out.txt`. Good luck.

Comment: what are you trying to do?  why not just `cat filenames.txt >>  logout.txt`

Comment: Because actually it's a log of a more complicated bash I use. But even the simplest output doesn't work

Comment: @shellter it's basically the output of a find function to a text file so it's : /home/p11/data/bamfiles/bamfile1.srt.bam etc until 54

Comment: @Barmar I'm sorry but I think it's not the same issue. My issue is that my file is not iterated to the end, not the fact I have an issue in the way the output is given

Comment: You're only echoing the first argument. If you don't quote the variable, that's just the first word in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote the command substitution. Otherwise `$1` will just be the first word in the file.

```
./log.sh "$(cat filenames.txt)"
```

You should also quote the variable in the script, otherwise all the newlines will be converted to spaces.

```
echo "$1" >> log_out.txt
```

If you want to process each word separately, you can leave out the quotes

```
./log.sh $(cat filenames.txt)
```

and then use a loop in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for word in "$@"
do
    echo "$word"
done >> log_out.txt
```

Note that this solution only works correctly when the file has one word per line and there are no wildcards in the words. See mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor for why this doesn't generalize to more complex lines.

Comment: Thanks I nevertheless have a new issue. Admitting I do a "echo "${1} is the file"
I have : 
file1 
file2
...
file 54 is the file 

I was expected to have the string added to each line. It causes me an issue because I use those paths as arguments for softwares, and it doesn't work anymore :/
thanks !

Comment: What's the issue with that?

Comment: It sounds like you need a loop

Comment: I indeed would like to use every file to be sent as an argument to 2 software which are in line (the second one needs the output of the first) for the 54 files

Comment: I've updated the answer, but you really need to put these details in the question, not just a comment.

Comment: Thanks it seems to works awesomely.
I've updated the question.

Comment: Kamil Cuk pointed below out why this won't be the best solution:
https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: @KarolFlis it's not a general solution, but it sounds like his file just has one word per line so it will work here.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your `./log.sh $(cat filenames.txt)` is being treated as one argument.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
 echo "$line";
done < filenames.txt
```

Edit according to: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Edit#2:

- To preserve leading and trailing whitespace in the result, set IFS to the null string.
- You could simplify more and skip using explicit variable and use the default `$REPLY`

Source: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read

Comment: Just, as a side note, include that [dont read lines with for](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and [how to read file line by line in bash](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Also escaping is important, probably op means `"${i}"`

Comment: Thanks, can I with while IFS send that to my bash script? (it's more complicated than just an echo)
Thanks !

Comment: Of course. Instead of echo "$line" you have to use that "$line" variable as an argument to your script: ./log.sh "$line"

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate with each line.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $*
do
  echo $i >> log_out.txt
done
```

Comment: Are you suggesting a glob? That would be `for i in *`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a glob because if I remove $ it doesn't take arguments.